# Create buffers postgis table from points using date filter

Tags: postgresql

I,m trying to create view or table where are polygons generated from point buffers  and group all polygons based on year.
Data fields from source table:

```
point_id(int), point_created(date), geom geometry(Point,3301)
    1, 2014-05-09, point
    2, 2015-01-01, point
    2, 2015-02-05, point
    3, 2016-02-05, point
    4, 2017-02-10, point
```

I was able to create table where I grouped all points by year and generated buffer as multipolygon but what I need is to group point based on date between years(group more than one year points together), so table must look like:

```
polygon(geom), nr_of_features(int), year(string)
 1, 1, 2014(all point from 2014)   
 2, 3, 2015(all points from 2014 to 2015)
 3, 4, 2016(all points from 2014 to 2016)
 4, 5, 2017(all points from 2014 to 2017)
```

Script I,m using right now:

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table as 
SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom,10))::geometry(MultiPolygon,3301) as polygon,count(point_id)::integer as nr_of_features,
extract(year from point_created) as year
FROM my_table
group by year;
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need something like that:

```
--just for create few years
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
    SELECT '2014-12-31'::timestamp years
    UNION ALL
    SELECT years + interval '1 year' FROM dates WHERE years < '2019-12-31'
)

SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.years) years,
    p.*
FROM 
    points p
INNER JOIN
    dates d ON p.date <= d.years
;
```

Now you can use the `years` column to aggregate the points.

Comment: Actually I tried it also,but problem is that its not grouping all points between date range  but still only one year points, sample: WHEN t.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' THEN 2015 give me result, where are all points from date 2015-01-01 to 2015-12-31, but I need all previous year points till the date 2015-12-31.

Comment: Sorry my answer was not correct, I updated it. The CASE...WHEN always stops at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify this script a little because  point dates is between 1994 and current date, so I changed you sample value '2014-12-31' to 2013-12-31 and '2019-12-31' to current_date. It seems working now, thanks you. I have 13000 points and it takes 173msec to create table using this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
    SELECT '1993-12-31'::timestamp years
    UNION ALL
    SELECT years + interval '1 year' FROM dates WHERE years < current_date
)

SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.years) years,
    ST_Multi(ST_Collect(geom))::geometry(MultiPoint,3301) as polygon, count(years)::int as nr_features
FROM 
    my_table p
INNER JOIN
    dates d ON p.point_created <= d.years
   group by years
   order by years asc;
```